# Setting data from Android Volley to variable

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a Volley request, and I'm trying to get the results set in a variable, but I get the error "Variable 'stuff' is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final." The problem is, once I declare it as final, I'm not allowed to set the variable equal to the response (like I'm trying to in the try block). I've looked around for the other questions that discuss this, but none have really been helpful to my situation.
Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList getStuff() {
    ArrayList<JSONObject> stuff;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue =     MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
            String url ="http://localhost:6000/stuff";

            RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
            // Testing out blocking
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);

            try {
                String response = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                stuff = response;
                Log.i("tutors after blocked: ", tutors);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // I want to be able to return 'stuff' here
    return stuff;

}
```

Comment: Then you have to declare it as final.But you will got a null arrayList returned.Cause when it returns ,the new thread is still running and did't get the data yet.

Comment: try this `final ArrayList<JSONObject> stuff;`

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this, but when I declare it as final, then I'm not allowed to set stuff = response (in the try block). That's the problem I was facing. I'll edit the post to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the word final as indicated below.

```
public ArrayList getStuff() {
final ArrayList<JSONObject> stuff; <--Add final here
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue =     MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        String url ="http://localhost:6000/stuff";

        RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        // Testing out blocking
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        try {
            String response = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            stuff = response;
            Log.i("tutors after blocked: ", tutors);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

// I want to be able to return 'stuff' here
return stuff;
```

}

Comment: But then I get the error "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'stuff'"

Answer (score 0):

Just move that variable declaration outside the method. this means it is already a Global Variable of that class

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> stuff;

public ArrayList getStuff() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue =     MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
            String url ="http://localhost:6000/stuff";

            RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
            // Testing out blocking
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);

            try {
                String response = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                stuff = response;
                Log.i("tutors after blocked: ", tutors);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // I want to be able to return 'stuff' here
    return stuff;

}
```

Comment: But then I get the error "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'stuff'"

Comment: Try moving it into the runnable just after the public void run() {.

Comment: That defeats the purpose. I'm trying to make this variable accessible to the rest of the function getStuff() @Mr.Ed

Comment: If I understand correctly, It sounds like you want a global variable.

Comment: @ProjectProgramAMark how come? you should remove the final like what my code is written

Answer (score 0):

After digging so much I got something in my mind that **SharedPreferences**,

If you really want response data  outside , You can use SharedPreferences to store the response value in some variable and read the same value outside whenever you want.

**To set value to the variable**

```
String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("returnResponse", "success");
editor.apply();
```

**To get value of the variable**

```
String return_value = sharedpreferences.getString("returnResponse", "");
```